# PowerDNS second view

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, powerdns

I use bind9, where i configured two views: for my localnet i have one set of internal ip addresses, for all other i have second set of external ip addresses.

Example from my named.conf:

```
acl "internal" { 172.16.0.0/16; };
view "internal" {
    match-clients {"internal";}; 
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion {172.16.0.0/16; };
    zone "example.ru" {
    type master;
    file "VIEW/example.ru.int";
    };
    zone "jira.example.ru" {
    type master;
    file "VIEW/jira.example.ru.int";
    };
    include "zones.conf";
};

view "external" {
    match-clients {"any";};
    recursion no;

    zone "example.ru" {
    type master;
    file "VIEW/example.ru.ext";
    };
    zone "jira.example.ru" {
    type master;
    file "VIEW/jira.example.ru.ext";
    };
    include "zones.conf";
};
```

Now, i want to migrate all my zones to PowerDNS, but i need to keep second view. I can`t find how to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

PowerDNS Server does not support BIND9-style DNS "views". While the geobackend can be used to provide some of its functionality it is generally advised to split internal and external DNS resource records at domain level instead.

Lua Scripting could be used on both recursor and/or server to work around those limitations because you the source IP for the query is exposed to the Lua code but you would have to write and maintain your own code there.